# document.cloneNode(true) is not cloning the iframes contentDocument

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I'm working on a project where I need to clone a DOM tree document to apply some changes and make assumption on the document without affecting the original one.
I'm running into an issue when using `document.cloneNode(true)`. The problem is that the `iframe.contentDocument` properties of the children iframes of the cloned document are `undefined`, while they were defined in the original DOM.

Is there a workaround or alternative method to deep-clone a DOM element that includes iframes and ensures the `contentDocument` property is defined?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: No, `.contentDocument` is not an attribute and therefore not cloned. The cloned iframe is a separate element that would have to load its own content document.